Ubuntu became slow after updating to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
After updating to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, I noticed a few applications I use became slower:

Neovim: when auto completing commands in the bottom buffer (when typing : ) a rapid succession of commands flashes for a few frames. This didn't happen before the update and I just immediately got the completed command
QEMU: when running an Os I'm writing, it became noticeably slower. I didn't change any of the code, before the update it ran smoothly, afterwards it lagged while rendering on the frame buffer I'm on a Microsoft Surface Pro 8, with an 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1185G7 × 8, 16,0 GiB of memory.

Is anybody else experiencing this?
UPDATE: Reguarding qemu, I was able to regain performance somewhat by instead of using the invlpg x86 commnad to invalidate page tables, reloading cr3. I have no idea why this worked earlier and now is slow. I still have speed issues with the terminal (very minimal lag)

It is SooooOoooOOO  Slow When selecting a download location or a file to upload.
It is as if the system can not find it's parts.
When I say slow I mean 15 or 20 seconds sometimes longer for the dialog box to respond.
I have no clue why.
ASUS ROG STRIX Z690-E
64 Gigs Corasir memory
3 Terrabytes of SSDs
Gnome 46
Windowing X11
There should never be anything going so slow.
